# How to fix IndexOutOfBoundsException in RecyclerView (Jetpack Navigation, DataBinding)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-jetpack-navigation

My app uses "Jetpack Navigation, DataBinding, ViewModel".

A Fragment has RecyclerView.

If I touch one of the items, it is navigated to B Fragment.

And when I come back to A fragment (by back button), the crash occurs.

`IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter`

A Fragment is:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentABinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentABinding
        get() = _binding!!

    private val viewModel: AViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.vm = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.rvItems.adapter = ItemsAdapter()
        viewModel.getItems()
    }

}
```

A ViewModel is:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val itemRepo: ItemRepo,
    private val disposable: CompositeDisposable
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _items: MutableLiveData<List<Item>> = MutableLiveData()
    val items: LiveData<List<Item>>
        get() = _items

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        disposable.clear()
    }

    fun getItems() {
        itemRepo.getAll()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                _items.postValue(it)
            }, { t ->

            })
            .addTo(disposable)
    }
}
```

XML Layout is:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:bind_items="@{vm.items}"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Binding Adapter is:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind_items")
fun setItems(view: RecyclerView, list: List<Item>?) {
    if (!list.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        (view.adapter as? ItemsAdapter)?.update(list)
    }
}
```

ItemsAdapter is:

```
class ItemsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ItemHolder>() {

    private val items: MutableList<Item> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemHolder {
        return ItemHolder (ItemItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
    }

    fun update(newItems: List<Item>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(newItems)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newItems.size)
    }

    class ItemHolder(
        private val binding: ItemItemBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: Item) {
            with(binding) {
                tvDate.text = item.date
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this issue is related to the "Jetpack Navigation".

But I don't know exactly what should I do...

Comment: what does `ItemsAdapter.update` do ?

Comment: I added the adapter code too

Comment: what does this `notifyItemInsertRange(0, newItems.size)` method do?  As far as I can see it is not a standard method - this : `Adapter::notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)` or `Adapter::notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)` is the method you'd usually call.  Consider using the DiffUtil class or even a `ListAdapter` that uses a `AsyncListDiffer` to work out and apply changes for you.

Comment: It is just wrong typing... I used `notifyItemRangeInserted` right.

Answer (score 1):

From the android documentation of `RecyclerView.Adapter` of `notifyItemRangeInserted`:

> Notify any registered observers that the currently reflected itemCount items >starting at positionStart have been newly inserted. The items previously located at >positionStart and beyond can now be found starting at position positionStart + >itemCount.

This means that after you call that function the adapter expects the list to be long oldList.size + newList.size, but finds only the new elements and so goes out of bounds.

The simplest solution is to use `notifyDataSetChanged` instead, though you may want to use other solutions for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling the adapter when you remove the items, you'd have to do something like this:

```
fun update(newItems: List<Item>) {

    // remove the old items
    val originalSize = items.size
    items.clear()
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, originalSize)

    // add the new items
    items.addAll(newItems)
    notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newItems.size)
}
```

But this is going to look a bit weird, I doubt that's what you want (it will animate the old items out, and then animate the new items in). Like the previous answer suggested, the easiest way is to use **notifyDataSetChanged** instead (the list will just change visually immediately with no animations)

```
fun update(newItems: List<Item>) {
    items.clear()
    items.addAll(newItems)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

If you want nice change animations, you should probably look into **DiffUtil** (that will calculate the difference between your two lists - but it is an expensive call for large lists). You can get away with running on the UI thread for small lists, but you shouldn't really (using DiffUtil off the UI thread is quite a bit more complicated if you want to guarantee robust code). You could get the DiffResult like this:

```
fun createDiffResult(oldList: List<Thing>, newList: List<Thing>): DiffUtil.DiffResult {

    return DiffUtil.calculateDiff(object : DiffUtil.Callback() {

        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
            return oldList.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
            return newList.size
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {

            // are the items conceptually the same item?
            // (you might compare a unique id here)

            return true
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {

            // do the items _look_ the same when rendered in your recycler view?
            // (you only need to compare the values for the things that are visible in your implementation of the item view)

            return true
        }
    })
}
```

then use it like this:

```
diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter);
```